# How to view excel file in jsp page using java code?

Tags: java, excel, jsp, jakarta-ee

How to view Excel file in JSP page using Java code?

I want to show the **Excel page directly in JSP page** not only the data. Fully Excel page with Excel format.

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
}
```

Comment: Check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3511179/display-excel-sheet-in-the-browser

Answer (score 0):

You can pass data from servlet to jsp using below code it works fine Modules.java (Servlet page ) and Modules.jsp pages code is given below

```
FileInputStream file1 = new FileInputStream(new File("your_file_path"));
            System.out.println(file1);
            file.close();    
            //Create Workbook instance holding reference to .xlsx file
            XSSFWorkbook workbook111 = new XSSFWorkbook(file1);

            //Get first/desired sheet from the workbook
            XSSFSheet sheet111 = workbook111.getSheetAt(0);


            Object[][] bookData_read = new String[sheet111.getLastRowNum()+1][3];

            int row_count11 = 0;

            Iterator<Row> rowIterator111 = sheet111.iterator();

            while (rowIterator111.hasNext()) 
            {
                Row row111 = rowIterator111.next();
                if (row_count11 == 0) {
                    row_count11++;
                continue;

                }

                if (row_count11 > sheet111.getLastRowNum())
                    break;



                Cell cell11 = row111.getCell(4);
                String cellvalue1 = "";

                if (cell11 != null && ! "".equals(cell11.getStringCellValue()) ||cell11 != null && ! "".equals(cell11.getNumericCellValue())) {

                    switch (cell11.getCellType()) {

                        case Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING:
                            //System.out.print(cell.getStringCellValue());
                            cellvalue1 = cell11.getStringCellValue();
                            break;
                        case Cell.CELL_TYPE_BOOLEAN:
                            //System.out.print(cell.getBooleanCellValue());
                            cellvalue1 = "" + cell11.getBooleanCellValue();
                            break;
                        case Cell.CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC:
                            //System.out.print(cell.getNumericCellValue());
                            cellvalue1 = "" + cell11.getNumericCellValue();
                            break;

                    }}


                    String module1 = cellvalue1;
                    //System.out.println("module"+module1);
                    //System.out.println(cellvalue);
                    bookData_read[row_count11][0] = cellvalue1;


                    if(row111.getCell(5)!=null)
                    {
                          Cell cell2 = row111.getCell(5);
                          cellvalue1 = "";
                        if (cell2 != null && ! "".equals(cell2.getStringCellValue())) {



                    switch (cell2.getCellType()) {
                        case Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING:
                            //System.out.print(cell.getStringCellValue());
                            cellvalue1 = cell2.getStringCellValue();
                            break;
                        case Cell.CELL_TYPE_BOOLEAN:
                            //System.out.print(cell.getBooleanCellValue());
                            cellvalue1 = "" + cell2.getBooleanCellValue();
                            break;
                        case Cell.CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC:
                            //System.out.print(cell.getNumericCellValue());
                            cellvalue1 = "" + cell2.getNumericCellValue();
                            break;
                    }  }}
                    String submodule = cellvalue1;
                    //System.out.println("submodule"+submodule);

                   // System.out.println(cellvalue);
                    bookData_read[row_count11][1] = cellvalue1;



                   if(row111.getCell(5)!=null && ! "".equals(row111.getCell(5).getStringCellValue()) )
                   {
    //               if(row.getCell(7)!=null && ! "".equals(row.getCell(7).getStringCellValue()))
    //              {
    //                    
                    Cell  cell3 = row111.getCell(8);
                    cellvalue1 = "";
                    if (cell3 != null && ! "".equals(cell3.getStringCellValue())) {
                    switch (cell3.getCellType()) {
                        case Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING:

                            cellvalue1 = cell3.getStringCellValue();
                            break;
                        case Cell.CELL_TYPE_BOOLEAN:

                            cellvalue1 = "" + cell3.getBooleanCellValue();
                            break;
                        case Cell.CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC:

                            cellvalue1 = "" + cell3.getNumericCellValue();
                            break;}}


                   String  temp = cellvalue1;
                   bookData_read[row_count11][2] = cellvalue1;

                   }
                    else{

                       continue;
                    }


                   row_count11++;



            }
            workbook111.close();

    request.setAttribute("modulesList", bookData_read);
 RequestDispatcher rd = request.getRequestDispatcher("/All_Modules.jsp");
        rd.forward(request, response);
```

Modules.jsp page

```
<pre>  <%
    String[][] book_data = (String[][]) request.getAttribute("modulesList");
    System.out.println("book_data: " + book_data);
    %>
  <table class="table table-striped jambo_table bulk_action">
                        <thead>
                          <tr class="headings">

                            <th class="column-title"><center>Sr No. </center></th>
                            <th class="column-title"><center>Modules</center></th>
                            <th class="column-title"><center>Sub Modules </center></th>
                                  <th class="column-title"><center>Test Case ID</center></th>

                    <th class="column-title"><center>Select All&nbsp;&nbsp;<input type="checkbox" class="chkSelectAll btn btn-primary" /></center></th>
                         <th class="column-title"><center>Screen Shot&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</center></th>


                        </thead>
  <%
  int counter11 = 1;
  for (String[] device : book_data) {
      if (device[0] != null && device[2] != null) {
          System.out.println("device[0]: " + device[0]);
  %>
    <tr>
        <td><center><%=counter11 %></center></td>
        <td><center><%=device[0] %></center></td>
        <td><center><%=device[1] %></center></td>
        <td><center><%=device[2] %></center></td>

        <td><center><input type="checkbox" id="check-all" class="flat" name="selectedmodules" value=<%=device[2]%>></center></td>
        <td><center><input type="checkbox" id="check-all" class="flat" name="screenshots" value=<%=device[2]%>></center></td>

    </tr>

  <%
    counter11++;
      }
  }
  %>
                       </table>
    </pre>
```

Answer (score 0):

For client, there is Excel and for web, there is Google Sheet.
If your reason for getting the whole Excel file is for formula, please check the following link.

https://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/formula.html

There are 350+ built-in functions POI has been supporting.
Or If you want your requirements to be happen no matter what, there is an option in IE browser that support ActiveX objects which will not be working in other operating systems.